# subset a datatable using multiple criteria from second table

Tags: r, datatable, subset

I have a very large datatable of ocean sites and multiple depths at each site (table 1).
I need to extract rows matching site location and depth in another datatable (Table 2).

Table 1 - table to be subset

| Lat | Long | Depth | Nitrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 165 | -77 | 0 | 29.5420 |
| 165 | -77 | 50 | 30.2213 |
| 165 | -77 | 100 | 29.2275 |
| 124 | -46 | 0 | 27.8544 |
| 124 | -46 | 50 | 28.6458 |
| 124 | -46 | 100 | 24.9543 |
| 76 | -24 | 0 | 31.9784 |
| 76 | -24 | 50 | 28.6408 |
| 76 | -24 | 100 | 24.9746 |
| 25 | -62 | 0 | 31.9784 |
| 25 | -62 | 50 | 28.6408 |
| 25 | -62 | 100 | 24.9746 |

Table 2 - co-ordinates and depth needed for subsetting:

| Lat | Long | Depth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 165 | -77 | 100 |
| 76 | -24 | 50 |
| 25 | -62 | 0 |

I have tried to get all sites in a table that would include all available depth data for those sites:

```
subset <- filter(table1, Lat == table2$Lat | Long == table2$Long)
```

but it returns zero obs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for an inner join:

```r
merge(dat1, dat2, by = c("Lat", "Long"))
#   Lat Long Depth.x Nitrate Depth.y
# 1 165  -77     100 29.2275     100
# 2 165  -77       0 29.5420     100
# 3 165  -77      50 30.2213     100
# 4  25  -62       0 31.9784       0
# 5  25  -62      50 28.6408       0
# 6  25  -62     100 24.9746       0
# 7  76  -24       0 31.9784      50
# 8  76  -24      50 28.6408      50
# 9  76  -24     100 24.9746      50
```

There is some risk in this: joins and such rely on strict equality when comparing columns, but floating-point (with many digits of precision) can become too "fine" for most programming languages to detect differences (c.f., [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). The problem with this problem is that you will get no errors, it just won't produce matches.

To work around *that* problem, you will need to think about "tolerance", or the distance between points in `dat1` and points in `dat2`, and what distance between all the points is effectively "close enough" to constitute a join. That can be done in one of two ways: (1) calculate the distance between all points in `dat1` and all points in `dat2`, and taking the minimum for each in `dat1` (and within a tolerance); or (2) do a "fuzzy join" (using the aptly named `fuzzyjoin` package) to find points that are within a range (effectively like `dat1$Lat between dat2$Lat +/- 0.01` and similar for `Long`).

---

Data

```r
dat1 <- structure(list(Lat = c(165L, 165L, 165L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 25L, 25L, 25L), Long = c(-77L, -77L, -77L, -46L, -46L, -46L, -24L, -24L, -24L, -62L, -62L, -62L), Depth = c(0L, 50L, 100L, 0L, 50L, 100L, 0L, 50L, 100L, 0L, 50L, 100L), Nitrate = c(29.542, 30.2213, 29.2275, 27.8544, 28.6458, 24.9543, 31.9784, 28.6408, 24.9746, 31.9784, 28.6408, 24.9746)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
dat2 <- structure(list(Lat = c(165L, 76L, 25L), Long = c(-77L, -24L, -62L), Depth = c(100L, 50L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: table 1 is a very large file - 1,917,030 obs. table 2 is 228 obs.

Comment: What impact do you think that fact has on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

`paste` `Lat` and `Long` columns together of both the tables and select rows that match.

```
result <- subset(table1, paste(Lat, Long) %in% paste(table2$Lat, table2$Long))
result
```